# overlaying text on image with flickity?

Tags: javascript, css

using [flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/), how do i overlay vertically and horizontally aligned text on some images?

here is my jade:

```
.gallery
  .cell
    h2 One
    img(src="01.jpg")
  .cell
    h2 Two
    img(src="02.jpg")
  .cell
    h2 Three
    img(src="03.jpg")
```

and my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.gallery').flickity({
autoPlay: 3000,
prevNextButtons: false


});    
});
```

I tried [this](https://css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/) but the second and third images appear shrunk. Any clues?

Comment: Do you have a demo online for this?